# Fit table cells to the content in table with many columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table with many columns and I want the columns to be fit to their max cell content.

It works properly if I have only few columns, but if I have many columns it does not work. I want each row to be in one row.

```css
.rTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.rTableCell,
.rTableCellError,
.rTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table class="rTable" style="width:100%">
  <thead class="rTableHeading">
    <tr class="rTableRow">
      <th class="rTableHead"># Time</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Exec Status</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Fail Reason</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Temp Sensor</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">SvDrop Version</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Band</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Measured current</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">#i</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Temperature</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Power Supply 1.8 Voltage I</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Power Supply 1.8 Voltage II</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Power Supply 3.3 Voltage I</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Power Supply 3.3 Voltage II</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Power Supply 1.24 Voltage</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Power Supply 1 Voltage</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Chain</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Additional Chain</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">BB Filter</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Current Mode</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">PA IntrExtrSelect</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">MixerFreqTune</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">PA DRV Gain</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">PA Core</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Mixer Gain</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Frequency [MHz]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">AbortTimeout</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Signal Tx Type</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">POUT-Limit-0</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">POUT-Limit-1</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">POUT-Limit-2</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">POUT-Limit-3</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">calibration summary</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">CablesLoss</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">BB CableLoss</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">ProjectLoss</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">BB ProjectLoss</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">XTAL_X1</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">XTAL_X2</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Band Gap</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">RTRIM</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">LO_iDC</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">LO_qDC</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">IQ_IQAMP</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">IQ_IQPHASE</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Calibration Captune</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">TimeSkew</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">PLL Lock</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">POUT [dBm]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">LO-Leakage [dBc]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">LO-Leakage [dBm]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">IQ-Imbalance [dBc]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">IQ-Imbalance [dBm]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">DVM Current [mA]</th>
      <th class="rTableHead">Tx Gain</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="rTableBody">
    <tr class="rTableRow ">
      <td class="rTableCell">12:19:22</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">OK</td>
      <td class="rTableCell"></td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Low</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">1.2956</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Ch1</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">NONE</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">WBPAPD</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Hi</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Internal</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">9</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Full_Core</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Full_Core</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">_0dB</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">_2412_Ch1_g</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Dac</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">{WiFiCableLoss : (CablesLoss : -7.013)}{DBoardLoss : (ProjectLoss : -0.835137789)}{CrystalCalibration : (XTAL_X1 : 463)(XTAL_X2 : 463) defult}{BandGapBuff : (Band Gap : 0.6) defult}{Rtrim : (RTRIM : 32) defult}{TxLoCalibration : (LO_iDC : 0)(LO_qDC
        : 0) defult}{TxIQMismatch : (IQ_IQAMP : 0)(IQ_IQPHASE : 0) defult}{TxMixerCap : (MixerFreqTune : 9)}</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">-7.013</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">-0.835137789</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">463</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">463</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0.6</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">32</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Yes</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">-4.4350</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCellError">31.6733 &#8214; [ > 35 ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rTableRow ">
      <td class="rTableCell">12:19:23</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">OK</td>
      <td class="rTableCell"></td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Hi</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">1.3091</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">1</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">null</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Ch1</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">NONE</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">WBPAPD</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Hi</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Internal</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">8</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Full_Core</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Full_Core</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">_0dB</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">_5500_Ch100_a</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Dac</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">{WiFiCableLoss : (CablesLoss : -10.578)}{DBoardLoss : (ProjectLoss : -0.67644533)}{CrystalCalibration : (XTAL_X1 : 463)(XTAL_X2 : 463) defult}{BandGapBuff : (Band Gap : 0.6) defult}{Rtrim : (RTRIM : 32) defult}{TxLoCalibration : (LO_iDC : 0)(LO_qDC
        : 0) defult}{TxIQMismatch : (IQ_IQAMP : 0)(IQ_IQPHASE : 0) defult}{TxMixerCap : (MixerFreqTune : 8) defult}</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">-10.578</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">-0.67644533</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">463</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">463</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0.6</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">32</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Not used</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">Yes</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">-1.4360</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCell">0</td>
      <td class="rTableCellError">34.6723 &#8214; [ > 35 ]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Eliminate all the classes and it will fit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the browser to "break" words you can use the `white-space: nowrap;` css attribute. Just add it to the your css:

```
.rTableCell, .rTableCellError, .rTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```css
    .rTable {
       display: table;
       width: 100%;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       border-spacing:0;
     }


    .rTableCell, .rTableCellError, .rTableHead {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<table class="rTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="rTableHeading">
      <tr class="rTableRow">
  <th class="rTableHead"> # Time </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Exec Status </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Fail Reason </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Temp Sensor </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> SvDrop Version </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Band </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Measured current </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> #i </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Temperature </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1.8 Voltage I </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1.8 Voltage II </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 3.3 Voltage I </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 3.3 Voltage II </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1.24 Voltage </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1 Voltage </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Chain </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Additional Chain </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> BB Filter </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Current Mode </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> PA IntrExtrSelect </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> MixerFreqTune </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> PA DRV Gain </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> PA Core </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Mixer Gain </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Frequency [MHz] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> AbortTimeout </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Signal Tx Type </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-0 </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-1 </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-2 </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-3 </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> calibration summary </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> CablesLoss </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> BB CableLoss </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> ProjectLoss </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> BB ProjectLoss </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> XTAL_X1 </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> XTAL_X2 </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Band Gap </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> RTRIM </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> LO_iDC </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> LO_qDC </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> IQ_IQAMP </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> IQ_IQPHASE </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Calibration Captune </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> TimeSkew </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> PLL Lock </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> POUT [dBm] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> LO-Leakage [dBc] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> LO-Leakage [dBm] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> IQ-Imbalance [dBc] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> IQ-Imbalance [dBm] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> DVM Current [mA] </th>
  <th class="rTableHead"> Tx Gain </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="rTableBody">
  <tr class="rTableRow ">
  <td class="rTableCell"> 12:19:22 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> OK </td>
  <td class="rTableCell">  </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Low </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 1.2956 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Ch1 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> NONE </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> WBPAPD </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Hi </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Internal </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 9 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> _0dB </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> _2412_Ch1_g </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Dac </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> {WiFiCableLoss : (CablesLoss : -7.013)}{DBoardLoss : (ProjectLoss : -0.835137789)}{CrystalCalibration : (XTAL_X1 : 463)(XTAL_X2 : 463) defult}{BandGapBuff : (Band Gap : 0.6) defult}{Rtrim : (RTRIM : 32) defult}{TxLoCalibration : (LO_iDC : 0)(LO_qDC : 0) defult}{TxIQMismatch : (IQ_IQAMP : 0)(IQ_IQPHASE : 0) defult}{TxMixerCap : (MixerFreqTune : 9)} </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> -7.013 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> -0.835137789 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0.6 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 32 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Yes </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> -4.4350 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCellError"> 31.6733 &#8214; [ > 35 ]  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="rTableRow ">
  <td class="rTableCell"> 12:19:23 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> OK </td>
  <td class="rTableCell">  </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Hi </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 1.3091 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 1 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Ch1 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> NONE </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> WBPAPD </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Hi </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Internal </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 8 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> _0dB </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> _5500_Ch100_a </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Dac </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> {WiFiCableLoss : (CablesLoss : -10.578)}{DBoardLoss : (ProjectLoss : -0.67644533)}{CrystalCalibration : (XTAL_X1 : 463)(XTAL_X2 : 463) defult}{BandGapBuff : (Band Gap : 0.6) defult}{Rtrim : (RTRIM : 32) defult}{TxLoCalibration : (LO_iDC : 0)(LO_qDC : 0) defult}{TxIQMismatch : (IQ_IQAMP : 0)(IQ_IQPHASE : 0) defult}{TxMixerCap : (MixerFreqTune : 8) defult} </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> -10.578 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> -0.67644533 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0.6 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 32 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> Yes </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> -1.4360 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
  <td class="rTableCellError"> 34.6723 &#8214; [ > 35 ]  </td>
 </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks it work when i use browser. But i want to send this html to email and the outlook not support this CSS tag. what the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for the table

```
th, td {    
padding: 25px;word-wrap:break-word}
```

Note: padding has to be made as per your situation

Answer (score 0):

The table will attempt to be as wide as desired by the content, like you want.

However, the problem comes when that is bigger than the available space. In that case, the table will attempt to avoid overflowing its containing block, forcing the contents from being narrower than their preferred width.

But anyways the table won't force the contents to be narrower than their minimum width.

So as Dekel answered, a solution is `white-space: nowrap`. By preventing the text from wrapping into multiple lines, you are setting the minimum width to be the same as the preferred width.

A more explicit solution is setting the `width` (or `min-width`, since you already use `width: 100%`) to `max-content`. Be aware it's a relatively recent keyword which may not be widely supported.

```css
.rTable {
  min-width: -webkit-max-content;
  min-width: -moz-max-content;
  min-width: max-content;
}
```

```css
.rTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  min-width: -webkit-max-content;
  min-width: -moz-max-content;
  min-width: max-content;
}
.rTableCell, .rTableCellError, .rTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table class="rTable" style="width:100%">
  <thead class="rTableHeading">
    <tr class="rTableRow">
      <th class="rTableHead"> # Time </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Exec Status </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Fail Reason </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Temp Sensor </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> SvDrop Version </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Band </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Measured current </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> #i </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Temperature </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1.8 Voltage I </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1.8 Voltage II </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 3.3 Voltage I </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 3.3 Voltage II </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1.24 Voltage </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Power Supply 1 Voltage </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Chain </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Additional Chain </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> BB Filter </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Current Mode </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> PA IntrExtrSelect </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> MixerFreqTune </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> PA DRV Gain </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> PA Core </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Mixer Gain </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Frequency [MHz] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> AbortTimeout </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Signal Tx Type </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-0 </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-1 </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-2 </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> POUT-Limit-3 </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> calibration summary </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> CablesLoss </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> BB CableLoss </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> ProjectLoss </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> BB ProjectLoss </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> XTAL_X1 </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> XTAL_X2 </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Band Gap </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> RTRIM </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> LO_iDC </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> LO_qDC </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> IQ_IQAMP </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> IQ_IQPHASE </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Calibration Captune </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> TimeSkew </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> PLL Lock </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> POUT [dBm] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> LO-Leakage [dBc] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> LO-Leakage [dBm] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> IQ-Imbalance [dBc] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> IQ-Imbalance [dBm] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> DVM Current [mA] </th>
      <th class="rTableHead"> Tx Gain </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="rTableBody">
    <tr class="rTableRow ">
      <td class="rTableCell"> 12:19:22 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> OK </td>
      <td class="rTableCell">  </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Low </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 1.2956 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Ch1 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> NONE </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> WBPAPD </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Hi </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Internal </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 9 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> _0dB </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> _2412_Ch1_g </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Dac </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> {WiFiCableLoss : (CablesLoss : -7.013)}{DBoardLoss : (ProjectLoss : -0.835137789)}{CrystalCalibration : (XTAL_X1 : 463)(XTAL_X2 : 463) defult}{BandGapBuff : (Band Gap : 0.6) defult}{Rtrim : (RTRIM : 32) defult}{TxLoCalibration : (LO_iDC : 0)(LO_qDC : 0) defult}{TxIQMismatch : (IQ_IQAMP : 0)(IQ_IQPHASE : 0) defult}{TxMixerCap : (MixerFreqTune : 9)} </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> -7.013 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> -0.835137789 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0.6 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 32 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Yes </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> -4.4350 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCellError"> 31.6733 &#8214; [ > 35 ]  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rTableRow ">
      <td class="rTableCell"> 12:19:23 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> OK </td>
      <td class="rTableCell">  </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Hi </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 1.3091 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 1 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> null </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Ch1 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> NONE </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> WBPAPD </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Hi </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Internal </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 8 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Full_Core </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> _0dB </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> _5500_Ch100_a </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Dac </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> {WiFiCableLoss : (CablesLoss : -10.578)}{DBoardLoss : (ProjectLoss : -0.67644533)}{CrystalCalibration : (XTAL_X1 : 463)(XTAL_X2 : 463) defult}{BandGapBuff : (Band Gap : 0.6) defult}{Rtrim : (RTRIM : 32) defult}{TxLoCalibration : (LO_iDC : 0)(LO_qDC : 0) defult}{TxIQMismatch : (IQ_IQAMP : 0)(IQ_IQPHASE : 0) defult}{TxMixerCap : (MixerFreqTune : 8) defult} </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> -10.578 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> -0.67644533 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 463 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0.6 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 32 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Not used </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> Yes </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> -1.4360 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCell"> 0 </td>
      <td class="rTableCellError"> 34.6723 &#8214; [ > 35 ]  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```